# Why am I getting NaN in my local file but my fiddle is fine

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling to see why I'm getting NaN in my local file, but in my fiddle it works perfectly.

I've checked to see if I've left out any id's in the HTML but it all looks in order. I can't see why it is returning NaN.

Here is a part of my JavaScript which I think is causing the problem:

```
function updateCost() {

    var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value) || 0.00,
        delivery = parseFloat(document.getElementById("delivery").value),
        total = amount + delivery,
        fixedrate =  total / 100 * 12.2,
        grandtotal = fixedrate + total;   

    document.getElementById("amountdiv").innerHTML = amount.toFixed(2);   
    document.getElementById("deliverydiv").innerHTML = delivery.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("fixedrate").innerHTML = fixedrate.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("grandtotal").innerHTML = grandtotal.toFixed(2);

}

    // handle the due date
    var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
    var monthNames = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July", "August","September","October","November","December");    
    var todayPlus30 = new Date();
    todayPlus30.setDate(todayPlus30.getDate()+30)
    var dateStr = (dayNames[todayPlus30.getDay()] + ", " + monthNames[todayPlus30.getMonth()+1] + " " +  todayPlus30.getDate()  + ", " +  todayPlus30.getFullYear());

    $('#date').html(dateStr);

$(function(){
    document.getElementById("amount").onchange =
    document.getElementById("delivery").onchange = updateCost;
});  

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#amount').change(function(){ updateCost(); });
    $('#delivery').change(function(){ updateCost(); });

});

$(function(){
$("#amount").keypress( function(e) {
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (".1234567890NOABC".indexOf(chr) < 0)
        return false;
});
});

$("#amount").blur(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
    if (/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/.test(input)) {
        var amount = parseFloat(input);
        if (amount < 40 || amount > 200) {
            $("span.paymentalert").html("Your payment must be between £40 and £200");
        } else {
            $("span.paymentalert").html("");
        }
    } else {
        $("span.paymentalert").html("Your payment must be a number");
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you load jquery locally?

Comment: where youre getting nan?

Comment: @Ark I'm getting Nan for 'fixedrate', 'total', 'grandtotal' and 'deliverydiv'.

Comment: Add html plz. we are guessing instead of testing and giving the right answer.

Comment: @s.lenders Ok, 'amount' is an input field. 'delivery' is a select field and the others are output divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function like:

```
function updateCost() {

    var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value) || 0.00;
    var delivery = document.getElementById("delivery").value;
    if(delivery !='select' && delivery)
    {
        delivery=parseFloat(delivery);
    }
    else
    {
       delivery=0.00;
    }
    var total = amount + delivery;
    var fixedrate =  total / 100 * 12.2;
    var grandtotal = fixedrate + total;   

    document.getElementById("amountdiv").innerHTML = amount.toFixed(2);   
    document.getElementById("deliverydiv").innerHTML = delivery.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("fixedrate").innerHTML = fixedrate.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("grandtotal").innerHTML = grandtotal.toFixed(2);

}
```

Also you have written `onchange` function 2 times

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#amount').change(function(){ updateCost(); });
    $('#delivery').change(function(){ updateCost(); });
});
```

You can remove it

```
$(function(){
    document.getElementById("amount").onchange =updateCost;
    document.getElementById("delivery").onchange = updateCost;
});
```

Comment: This nearly worked Rohan, although the 'delivery' is a select field.  When I put 0.00.  It just returns 0.00.  It doesn't select the 'delivery' div correctly.

Comment: I changed my answer try that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missed something

```
$(function(){
document.getElementById("amount").onchange = // something should be here with statement end
document.getElementById("delivery").onchange = updateCost;
});
```

see the comment part, you have missed the amount initialization and termination of the statement too.

I hope this will solve the problem with NAN :)

Comment: also 
  $(function(){

  $("#amount").keypress( function(e) {

    var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

    if (".1234567890NOABC".indexOf(chr) < 0)

        return false;

  });

  });

I think this will be like
if (".1234567890".indexOf(chr) < 0) //NO ABC

correct this too.